# why using typename keyword when declaring vector iterator?

Tags: c++, typename

When I want to declare a iterator for vector, why do I need to use typename?

For example:

```
typename vector<T>::iterator i;
```

If I remove the keyword of `typename` then the program simply does not work. What I have written is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>

class MyClass
{
  private:
    vector<T>  array;

  public:
    MyClass ( T * begin,int n ) : array(n)
    {
      copy( begin, begin + n, array.begin());
    }

    void List()
    {
      typename vector<T>::iterator i;
      for( i = array.begin(); i != array.end(); ++i )
        cout << * i << "," ;
    }   
};


int main()
{
  string array[4] = { "Tom","Jack","Mary","John"};
  MyClass<string>obj(array,4);
  obj.List();
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to help others help you by saying which language this is. Also, avoid pasting your entire code; include only code relevant to the question ("this code doesn't work if I remove this keyword here" is not a good way to get help).

Comment: @Avish, see the tags. They are useful!

Comment: When I wrote my comment the only tag was `typename`. I considered adding a `C++` tag but decided to let the OP do that instead. @ClickRick thought otherwise :)

Comment: Oops, sorry...! @Wallace Cheng, think about what is happening when you use a template!

Comment: @Avish Thanks for your comment. I will ask question more professionally next time.

Comment: @G.Samaras Thanks. I didn't know much about typename in template.

Answer (score 5):

You use `typename` when you are inside a template and need to refer to a type that is dependent on a parameter of that template. In your code, `iterator` is a type that depends on `T`, so we use `typename`. If we were using, say, `int`, we wouldn't need `typename` because the type is not dependent on a template parameter:

```c++
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
```

This is spoken about in further detail in [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: You must use a typename, because the compiler doesn't know anything at compilation time!

Comment: @G.Samaras What do you mean by that?

Comment: I was referring to Wallace.

Comment: @userxyz  Thank you very much. I didn't know the existence of such dependency of typename and template parameters.